# If $CD = -DC$ Show that either $C$ or $D$ has no inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I'm probably missing something obvious, but how would I go about solving this?

Comment: Use determinants...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\det(CD)&=&\det(-DC)\\
\det(C)\cdot\det(D)&=&(-1)^n\det(D)\cdot\det(C)\qquad/n\,\mathtt{odd}\\
\det(C)\cdot\det(D)&=&-\det(D)\cdot\det(C)\\
\end{array}$$

So, either $\det(C)=0$ or $\det(D)=0$, so either $C$ or $D$ has no inverse.

Comment: The argument fails if $\ 2 = 0,\,$ i.e. over fields of characteristic $\,2.\ \ $

Comment: as the OP tags the question as linear algebra and matrices, I assumed that it needed only the basics, and there was no need of deeper maths. ;)

Comment: Nowadays linear is often done over finite fields (even in applied math), and it's not usually consider deeper math.